# Como hago select desde Php en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer un simple select desde mysql ¿cómo hago? ¿creo que seria algo así?

```
<?php
mysql_conect('127.0.0.1','root','clave');
mysql_query ('Select coluna1,colunna2 from tabla')
?>
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, utilizas algún framework como CodeIgniter,Laravel o programas en php sin ningún framework?

Comment: Sería mejor saber que versión de PHP usa y no si usa un framework!

Comment: @PakLeiChong al parecer Juan está utilizando PHP puro. En mi tiempo de desarrollo con PHP no sabía que era necesario siempre trabajar con algún framework para comunicarse con la base de datos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma correcta (y recomendad por PHP) es usar la extensión MySQLi (puedes leer más aquí: [Extensión MySQL mejorada](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php))

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "usuario", "password", "base_de_datos");
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM TABLA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen también eso va a depender mucho de si estas usando algún framework como laravel o codeigniter, pero como lo pones en tu ejemplo asumo que es estructurado; 
Primero creas tu archivo

**conexion.php**

> $hostname_cn = "localhost";//o puedes poner tu 127.0.0.1'
>
> $database_cn = "base de datos";
>
> $username_cn = "root";
>
> $password_cn = "xxx";
>
> $cn = mysqli_connect($hostname_cn, $username_cn, $password_cn,
>   $database_cn) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

**index.php**

> ---
>
> `<?php require_once('conexion.php');`  //incluyes el archivo conexion

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulo";//preparas tu query
```

> ```
> $rs = mysqli_query($cn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error()); //ejecutas la consulta
>
> while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs)){  //siempre usa while para hacer el recorrido
>          $variable = $row["nombre de las columna de bd"]; y así con las demás columnas de la tabla seleccionada
>
>
>         }                                   
>         ?>
> ```

si tu quieres cortas el php y le pones el html y dibujas un div y lo imprimes dentro el `<?php  echo $variable ?>`

Recuerda si vas a ser esto en un framework con codeigniter te olvidas de conexion; y solo configuras en archivos databases.php y solo llenas los parametros asi como el de la imagen,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno tendria que hablar sobre el Mvc pero creo que eso no es el punto del tema bueno, un framework siempre simplifica la vida.

Comment: es que tambien se puede hacer el select como antes se hacia sin la extension de mysqli solo usando mysql  a mi me funciona asi en mi local pero cuando lo subo a mi hosting ya no funciona pero actualmente algunos hosting trabajan con mysqli por la seguridad, y ademas que es orientado a objetos

Comment: ok, bueno como en su ejemplo el lo trataba asi, me parecio que seria buena la observacion