# Insertar campos de MySQL a formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario alojado en Linux que tiene distintos campos (nombre, email y checkbox). Los datos que se recojan del formulario van a una base de datos SQL alojada en Windows. Ambos servidores están en la misma red, por lo que para hacer este paso de introducir los datos del formulario en la bd, utilicé este código:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.3", "vmb", "vmb2", "logytel") or die ("Problemas al conectar");
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prueba");

    $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()

    echo $fila['nombre'];
    echo $fila['instalacion'];
    echo $fila['email'];
    echo $fila['fallo_fisico'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
    <form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" role="form" action="guardar.php">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br><br>
                    <br><label for="nombre">Su nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a title="Logytel" href="http://logytel.es"><img class="logytel" src="https://i2.wp.com/logytel.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-LOGO_Logytel_2012_R_485C_24x10_8_Blanco.png" alt="Logytel" /></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br><p>¿El equipo está correctamente instalado?</p>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <br><label class="container">Sí
                        <input type="checkbox" name="instalacion" value="1"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <br><label class="container">No
                        <input type="checkbox" name="instalacion" value="0"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
                    <br><br>
                    <br><label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="usuario@gmail.com" required class="form-control">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <p>¿El equipo tiene algún fallo físico?</p>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <br><label class="container">Sí
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fallo_fisico" value="1"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <br><label class="container">No
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fallo_fisico" value="0"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </div>
           </div>
        </div>

                <button id="myBtn" class="button" input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="resultado">Enviar</button>

</form>
</div>
        <script>
            var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
            /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
            a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            x[i].appendChild(a);
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
            for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
                /*for each option in the original select element,
                create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
                c = document.createElement("DIV");
                c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
                c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
                    and the selected item:*/
                    var y, i, k, s, h;
                    s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                    h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                        s.selectedIndex = i;
                            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                            }
                                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    h.click();
                    });
                b.appendChild(c);
            }
            x[i].appendChild(b);
            a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
                and open/close the current select box:*/
                e.stopPropagation();
                closeAllSelect(this);
                this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
                this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
                });
            }
            function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
            /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
            except the current select box:*/
            var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
            y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                    arrNo.push(i)
                    } else {
                    y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
                    }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
                }
            }
        }
        /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
        then close all select boxes:*/
        document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Entonces estuve buscando el cómo hacerlo al revés. Introducir un campo, por ejemplo, un select, para que aparezcan los datos registrados en la base de datos. He estado buscando, pero solo encuentro la parte php-sql y no al revés.

Pondré un ejemplo práctico para que se me entienda mejor:
Tengo un formulario que utilizarán los trabajadores que salgan de la empresa a revisar los equipos. En el campo  Para ahorrarle trabajo al empleado, se introducirá un campo en el que puedan escribir parte de su nombre y automáticamente, conectado a la bd correspondiente, le aparezca su nombre como sugerencia a introducir.

Version de PHP: 7
MySQL Server Windows
Formulario alojado en Fedora 28
Base de datos alojada en Windows Server 2008r2

Comment: Si utilizas el buscador, te aparecerán unas cuantas respuestas. Por ejemplo en [este enlace[(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19873/como-hago-select-desde-php-en-mysql) tienes una respuesta bastante elaborada que se ciñe a tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya estuve mirando, pero no me funciona...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay que tener varias cosas en cuenta con PHP y HTML, a la hora de mostrar datos.

1. Si tienes un archivo con extension **.html** no se podran mostrar datos provenientes de PHP ya que este no esta procesando el archivo.
2. Una vez tengas el archivo con extensión **.php** puedes incluir la parte de php en la parte superior y después tu código html y hacer **echo** de los valores que necesitas que se muestren al usuario.

Puedes ir intercalando bloques de PHP y HTML (Aun que no es lo recomendado te dara una visión simple de como funciona).

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.3", "vmb", "vmb2", "logytel") or die ("Problemas al conectar");
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prueba");

    $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><?php echo $fila['nombreDelCampo']; ?>'</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Con relación a select debes hacer la query arriba y cuando llegues a la parte del form seria de la siguente maneras, supongamos que el resultado de nuestra query esta en una variable `$options', el html seria asi.

```
  <select name="" id="">
    <?php
      foreach ($options as $option) {
        <option value="<? echo $option['id']; ?>"><? echo $option['name']; ?></option>
      }
    ?>
  </select>
```

Asumiendo que los campos traídos son id y name de cada registro de nuestro select.

Comment: Probaré mañana con lo dicho, ya te diré, ¡gracias!

Comment: Tengo un problema, he insertado en mi index.html (donde estaba el formulario) la parte php que me indicaste arriba, y cuando entro vía web me sale literalmente los <echo> del archivo.

Comment: Lucía, lee atentamente la respuesta. En el punto 1 te indica: Si tienes un archivo con extension .html no se podran mostrar datos provenientes de PHP ya que este no esta procesando el archivo.

Comment: @RogerTorné Luego renombré el archivo con extensión php, añadí el html ahí con el php en la parte superior y ni siquiera se mostraba en la página web

Comment: Vale, lo primero que debemos hacer es simplificar todo, puede en la parte de arriba crear una variable `$prueba = 'Esto es una prueba;` y luego en la parte de html poner `<?php echo $prueba; ?>` si funciona es que todo va bien, lo otro es que en la parte deonde puse `$fila['nombreDelCampo']` debes de poner un nombre de campo valido, por que no conozco tu base de datos.

Comment: Vale, ocurre un problema al conectar con la base de datos, "Problemas al conectar" la ip está bien, el usuario y la contraseña igual...

Comment: Trata primero de conectare desde un cliente de base de datos, así descartas que sea algo de la red, también fíjate que las bases de datos suelen ser expuestas por un determinado puerto.

Comment: Disculpa, no entendí muy bien eso. ¿Conectarme desde un cliente, cómo? El puerto está por defecto, ¿es necesario especificarlo o abrir ese puerto en el router?

Comment: Puedes usa https://dbeaver.io/ para conectarte a tu bases de datos y descartar cualquier problema de red.

Comment: No había oído nunca de ese programa, ¿tendría que instalarlo en mi servidor web (alojado en Linux, donde está el formulario) o en cualquier otro equipo?

Comment: Lo puedes instalar en cualquier maquina solo es un programa para hacer consultas SQL a la base de datos, en este caso es es para probar que puedas conectarte correctamente.

Comment: Me aparece este error cuando me intento conectar "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: Parece que no estás pidiendo acceder a esa IP, hagamos algo más simple así validamos que sea eso cambia en la parte de conexión esto `or die(mysql_error());` ahi te mostrará el error que pasa directamente desde el script.

Comment: Disculpa por el lío, me acabo de percatar que escribí otra dirección diferente, cambié a la correcta que conecta con el servidor sql, y me aparece el siguiente error "Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'vmb'."

Answer (score 2):

```
Esto es un archivo "index.php", espero que te sirva:

<?php
echo"Hello World !<br><br>";
if(!$_POST):
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username   = "root";
   $password   = "xxxx";
   $dbname     = "bd_Trabajadores";
   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
   // Check connection
   if($conn->connect_error)
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   // Create database
   $sql_Trab = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname;";
   if($conn->query($sql_Trab) === TRUE):
      // echo "Base de Data creada exitosamente";
   else:
       echo "Error creando Base de Data: " . $conn->error; exit;
   endif;
   // Conectamos con el controlador de MariaDB / MySQL //
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   //
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_Trabajadores
            (n_ID        INT (11),
             c_Nom       CHAR(30),
             c_CD        CHAR(15),
           PRIMARY KEY (n_ID),
           UNIQUE  KEY idx_Nom (c_Nom));";
   // echo"<br>";
   if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE):
      // echo "Tabla Trabajadores creada exitosamente";
   else:
      echo "Error creando Tabla Trabajadores: " . $conn->error; exit;
   endif;
   // Buscamos los Registros en Tabla de Trabajadores //
   //
   $sql_Trab = "SELECT * FROM t_Trabajadores;";
   //
   if($sel_Trab = $conn -> query($sql_Trab)):
      // echo "Consulta a la Tabla de Trabajadores exitosa";
   else:
      //
      echo "Línea ".__LINE__."<br><br>Error:<br><br>" . $sql_Trab . "<br>" . $bd -> error; exit;
      //
   endif;
   //
   $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO  t_Trabajadores
                              (n_ID,  c_Nom,                    c_CD       ) VALUES
                              (1   , 'ARMANDO SANCHEZ TORRES' , 'BARCELONA'),
                              (2   , 'FERNANDO GALICIA ZAMORA', 'MADRID'   ),
                              (3   , 'OSWALDO ZEPEDA TOLEDO'  , 'CDMX'     ),
                              (4   , 'PEDRO ALARCON HIDALGO'  , 'MONTERREY')";
   //
   if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE):
      // echo "New record created successfully";
   else: 
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; exit;
   endif;
   //
   // $conn->close();
   ?>
   <html>
         <body>
         <form action=index.php method=post name=index_php id=index_php>
               <br><br>
               <select name=sel_Trab id=sel_Trab onClick="document.getElementById('txt_c_CD').value=this.value;"><option>ELIJA UNA TRABAJADOR</option>
                       <?php
                       //
                       while($reg_Trab = $sel_Trab -> fetch_assoc()):
                             //
                             $n_ID  = $reg_Trab['n_ID' ];
                             $c_Nom = $reg_Trab['c_Nom'];
                             $c_CD  = $reg_Trab['c_CD' ];
                             //
                             echo "<option value='$n_ID - $c_Nom - $c_CD'> $c_Nom </option>";
                             //
                       endwhile; // $reg_Trab = $sel_Trab -> fetch_assoc()
                       // ?>
               </select>
               <input type=text id=txt_c_CD size=50px>
               <br><br>
               <button type=submit id=btn_Envio value=ENVIAR>ENVIAR</button>
         </body>
   </html>
   <?php
else: // !$_POST
   if($_POST) {
      foreach ($_POST as $clave=>$valor) {
         echo "El valor de < $clave > es: < $valor ><br>";
      }
   } else {
      echo 'No hay $_POST<br>';
   }
   echo "<br>";
   //
   $sel_Trab = $_POST['sel_Trab'];
   //
   $pos_Fin = strpos ( $sel_Trab , ' - ' );
   $n_ID = substr( $sel_Trab, 0, $pos_Fin ); echo ".$n_ID. " . strlen( $n_ID ) . "<br>";
   //
   $pos_Ini = $pos_Fin + 3;
   $pos_Fin = strpos ( $sel_Trab , ' - ', $pos_Ini );
   $lon_Str = $pos_Fin - $pos_Ini;
   $c_Nom = substr( $sel_Trab, $pos_Ini, $lon_Str ); echo ".$c_Nom. " . strlen( $c_Nom ) . "<br>";
   //
   $pos_Ini = $pos_Fin + 3;
   $lon_Str = strlen( $sel_Trab ) - $pos_Ini;
   $c_CD  = substr( $sel_Trab, $pos_Ini, $lon_Str ); echo ".$c_CD. " . strlen( $c_CD ) . "<br>";
   //
endif; // !$_POST
//
// Fin del Código
```