# Como listar los campos de mi consulta Select distinct en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, lista

Estoy ejecutando una consulta en mysql de un select distinct y en mysql me da los resultados que yo estoy esperando sin embargo, en PHP no se como listar ese resultado de mysql.
mi consulta es esta:

```
SELECT store,
       order, 
       count(DISTINCT order) AS order 
FROM pedidos 
GROUP BY store 
ORDER BY store ASC
```

Comment: Si nunca has realizado conexiones y consultas a base de datos desde PHP podrias revisar algunos tutoriales https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp o si ya tienes algo en curso, compartir el codigo que tengas hasta ahora, Hay distintas librerias de conexion posibles

Comment: Tambien revisa la respuesta de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19873/como-hago-select-desde-php-en-mysql

Comment: @F.Igor en vez de recomendar código de `w3schools`, es mejor referir en cada caso  la documentación oficial. `w3schools` está bien posicionado en Google, pero tiene código desactualizado a veces o implementan malas prácticas de programación. El asunto fue debatido durante un tiempo en la comunidad de programadores (aunque es cierto que gracias a las críticas `w3schools` mejoró mucho). Para más detales ver [aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/5587982) y [aquí](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4975/186960)

Comment: Ok @A.Cedano gracias por la aclaracion. En la documentación oficial puede encontrarse una introducción al uso de conexiones de base de datos usando PDO en https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php